# "Disk I/O error" when trying to run OS via QEMU on Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, virtual-machine, qemu, disk-image

I am trying to run Windows 98 on QEMU on my Pi using a project I found here: https://www.hackster.io/314reactor/windows-98-wrist-watch-15ecfd . When I run

```
qemu-system-i386 -localtime -cpu 486 -m 96 -hda windows98.img
```

I am told

```
WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'Windows98.img' and probing guessed raw.
Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
```

QEMU still opens but it reads

```
Disk I/O error replace the disk then press any key
```

the same message continues to come up when any key is pressed. I ran the code

```
qemu-system-i386 -drive format=raw,file=Windows98.img
```

to try and get the raw format message to go away, which worked, however in QEMU the Disk I/O error message still appears.

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se] **:-)** It looks like something went wrong when you created the Windows 98 image file [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=117228)...

Comment: i downloaded the img file from a website online instead of that. I should have said that in my initial post.

Comment: Then it means you've got a corrupted image file. Please follow the process to create your own file or contact Microsoft for a CD (they can still be had)